# Viewing 3D Image with AMD Quad Buffer SDK - DirectX 9

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, stereo-3d

I am currently working on a project and I need to display 3D image using the images that had been taken with Bumblebee2 3D Camera.I am working on a MSI AE2420 computer and it has AMD HD 5730 with 3D support.I also have a shutter glass to see the images in stereo mode.

I am using DirectX 9 libraries( d3dx9.h ).IDE is VS 2008 Express Edition.

I have sample images(left and right) and I imported them to the program succesively with the lines;

```
pDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT,D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8,D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,&leftImageBuffer,NULL);
pDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT,D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8,D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,&rightImageBuffer,NULL);

D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFile(leftImageBuffer,NULL,NULL,"left0000.bmp",NULL,D3DX_FILTER_NONE,0,NULL)
D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFile(rightImageBuffer,NULL,NULL,"right0000.bmp",NULL,D3DX_FILTER_NONE,0,NULL)
```

After some research,I found that Direct3D9 does not allow active Quad Buffer stereo.So I cannot use four buffers(left front,left back , right front,right back).That's where AMD's Quad Buffer SDK involves in.They indicate that DirectX 9 do not allow active stereo as well and I need to use the functions of the SDK. I'm using  "AtiDx9Stereo.h" which is one of six header files in SDK(other five are for DirectX 11 and DirectX10).

However,after a lot of coding and testing ,I finally managed to enable stereo and now I can see the left image on the left side of the shutter glass,but in the right side of the glass I can see nothing.When I close my right I,I can see only left image.When I close my left eye,I see only a black page(or blue after cleaning the render target to blue or another color).Here is my render code and initialization of the pointers.If someone had been worked with these environment,that could be great to share some knowledge.

Initialization Statements

```
pD3D=Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
pD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,hWindow,64,&d3pp,&pDevice);
pDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(10,10,(D3DFORMAT)FOURCC_AQBS,D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,&driverCommSurface,NULL);
SendStereoCommand(ATI_STEREO_ENABLESTEREO, NULL, 0, 0, 0);
SendStereoCommand(ATI_STEREO_GETLINEOFFSET, (BYTE *)(&lineOffset), sizeof(DWORD), 0, 0);
```

After these statements, my render() function is is something like this;

```
D3DVIEWPORT9 viewPort;

    memset(&viewPort,0,sizeof(viewPort));
    pDevice->GetBackBuffer(0,0,D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO,&backBuffer);
    viewPort.X = 0;
    viewPort.Width = WINDOW_WIDTH;
    viewPort.Height = WINDOW_HEIGHT;

    if(SUCCEEDED(pDevice->BeginScene()))        //Start the device .
    {
        pDevice->SetRenderTarget(0, backBuffer);

        // Draw Right Eye Scene

        viewPort.Y = lineOffset;
        pDevice->SetViewport(&viewPort);
        pDevice->StretchRect(rightImageBuffer,NULL,backBuffer,NULL,D3DTEXF_LINEAR);




        // Draw Left Eye Scene

        viewPort.Y = 0;
        pDevice->SetViewport(&viewPort);
        pDevice->StretchRect(leftImageBuffer,NULL,backBuffer,NULL,D3DTEXF_LINEAR);

        backBuffer->Release();
        pDevice->EndScene();
        // Present both left and right buffers to the driver which will continuously
        // alternate between them until the next present

        pDevice->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);





        return S_OK;
    }
    return E_FAIL;
```

And in WINMAIN, I call render with these statements;

```
MSG msg;                                                    

    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0))
    {

        if(str.isReady)                     //If rendering fails,an error-message is shown.
        {
            str.SwitchToRightEye();
            str.pDevice->Clear(0,NULL,D3DCLEAR_TARGET,0x000000ff, 1.0f, 0.0f); 
            str.UpdateRightQuadBuffer();
            str.render();

        }

        TranslateMessage(&msg);                     //Translate and dispatch the messages for the getMessage loop.
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try;

```
viewPort.Height = lineOffset;
```

instead of

```
viewPort.Height = WINDOW_HEIGHT;
```

Comment: I tried that one also.It does not change anything.Even AMD do not provide any proper documentation for image or video stereo.Their forums are just crab.They do not answer any question! I will stay away from AMD from now on. nVidia has a lot of simple documents and their signature can be written to VRAM directly with swap command,so user do not need to write extra swap functions.I'm still working on that one.

I tried to start the project on OpenGL,but just because IZ3D do not allow OpenGL stereo on AMD ,I cannot even enable stereo mode!

Answer (score 0):

You should call SendStereoCommand(ATI_STEREO_SETDSTEYE,..) before and after StretchRect call for rightImageBuffer.

Something like that:

```
RECT destRect;

// Draw Right Eye Scene
destRect.top = lineOffset;
destRect.bottom = lineOffset + height;
viewPort.Y = lineOffset;

pDevice->SetViewport(&viewPort);

DWORD dwEye = ATI_STEREO_RIGHTEYE;
SendStereoCommand(ATI_STEREO_SETDSTEYE, NULL, 0, (BYTE *)&dwEye, sizeof(dwEye));

pDevice->StretchRect(rightImageBuffer,NULL,backBuffer,&destRect,D3DTEXF_LINEAR);    

// restore the destination
dwEye = ATI_STEREO_LEFTEYE;
SendStereoCommand(ATI_STEREO_SETDSTEYE, NULL, 0, (BYTE *)&dwEye, sizeof(dwEye)); 

// Draw Left Eye Scene
destRect.top = 0;
destRect.bottom = height;
viewPort.Y = 0;
pDevice->SetViewport(&viewPort);
pDevice->StretchRect(leftImageBuffer,NULL,backBuffer,&destRect,D3DTEXF_LINEAR);

...
```

and remove this code from WINMAIN:

```
str.SwitchToRightEye();
str.pDevice->Clear(0,NULL,D3DCLEAR_TARGET,0x000000ff, 1.0f, 0.0f); 
str.UpdateRightQuadBuffer();
```

**Update:**

I checked the code in our iZ3D Driver and I think you should, also, set correct destination rectangle in StretchRect calls for BackBuffer in accordance with lineOffset. This probably could work without changing viewport at all.

You should check that driver return you correct value for lineOffset (slightly bigger that backbuffer height) and HRESULT returned from SendStereoCommand().

Comment: I tried that one also and nothing changes.Just a black screen in the right glass instead of blue because I delete Clear() statement.I don't think that AMD stereo commands are working well.Because they do not effect anything.Besides,this line enables stereo ;

    pDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(10,10(D3DFORMAT)FOURCC_AQBS,D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,&driverCommSurface,NULL);

not the

     SendStereoCommand(ATI_STEREO_ENABLESTEREO,...)

Comment: I changed the program in a way that you said,however again in the right part,there is no image. There are a lot of if statements that checks for the HRESULT values and it seems like everything works fine.But lineOffset is not a so big value,it equals to 204.I found it while debugging .

Comment: yes it works.however, It does not matter if I delete the ENABLE_RIGHT or ENABLE_STEREO statements,demo still works in stereo mode.that is really interesting

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using a totally different method from AMD's documentation.And I think the functions in their SDK do not work properly. It was totally a waste of time for me to trying to follow that steps in documentation.

Here is the link for the project.

http://code.google.com/p/3d-viewer-buffer